# QPainter or QLabel is less costly to draw QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qpixmap, qlabel

I have to create an Icon pixmap, two methods I am familiarized to do that, One is setting the pixmap as o `QLabel` and display it, and other is drawing pixmap using `QPainter`, ie

Method one

```
Icon::Icon
{
    QLabel iconLab = new QLabel;
    QLabel iconName = new QLabel;
    iconLab->setPixmap("mypixmap.png"); 
    iconName->setText("myiconname");
    QVBoxLayout *iconLayout = new QVBoxLayout; 
    iconLayout->setMargin(0);
    iconLayout->addWidget(iconLab, 1, Qt::AlignCenter);
    iconLayout->addWidget(iconName, 1, Qt::AlignCenter);
    iconLayout->setSpacing(0);

    setLayout(iconLayout);
    setMaximumSize(100,160);
    setMinimumSize(100,160);
}
```

Method 2,

```
Icon::Icon
{     
    setMaximumSize(100,160);
    setMinimumSize(100,160);
}
Icon::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{      
    QPainter painter;
    painter.drawPixmap(0,0,myPixmap);
    painter.drawText(0,100,myText)
}
```

I have to draw number of Icons, more than 100, so which one is effective, 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you bothered to profile them and find out?

Comment: right now I am using the fist method. Because I was not much familiar with QPainter. I have read that drawing using paintEvent will reduce the speed, since it will execute whenever a screen update request comes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a theoretical perspective, the QPainter approach will be faster because the overhead introduced by QLabel is avoided. Internally QLabel needs to use a QPainter as well (using `drawPicture()`).

However, it is questionable if this difference will make your application more responsive. I doubt that this optimization will even be noticeable.

I would recommend to take care of code readability in the first place and take what is easier / feels better to use.

Once you have the functionality in place and there is a performance problem, you can start profiling and decide where the time and effort to optimize is best invested.

Comment: "From a theoretical perspective" - and practically too!

Comment: Practically QLabel does some caching and uses a different method than the one provided in the example (drawPixmap vs drawPicture). In practice it will depend on the QPainter implementation and usage (scaling involved etc.) if it is faster. I am sure that there is the possibility to implement a QPainter based approach that is slower than QLabel.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to draw more than 100 of this, this usually means that you should not use any of those solutions.
Most probably `QListView` with custom delegate and `QAbstractListModel` to hold those images is what you really need (or table version).

Comment: I am generating the Icon, there is no generated Icon, only a QPixmap and a QText  I have