# 4 ways to view Images in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qpainter

There are 4 ways to view Images in PyQt5.

First way: QLabel, QPixmap

```
label = QLabel(self)
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("landscape.jpg")
label.setPixmap(pixmap)
label.setGeometry(500,300,650,493)
```

Second way: QPainter, drawImage

```
painter = QPainter(self)
target = QRect(500,300,650,493)
source = QRect(0,0,650,493)
image = QImage("landscape.jpg")
painter.drawImage(target,image,source)
```

Third way: QPainter, drawPicture  (however, this gives me an 'Incorrect header' error)

```
painter = QPainter(self)
picture = QPicture()
picture.load("landscape.jpg")
painter.drawPicture(0,0,picture)
```

Fourth way: QPainter, drawPixmap

```
painter = QPainter(self)
target = QRect(500,300,650,493)
source = QRect(0,0,650,493)
pixmap = QPixmap("landscape.jpg")
painter.drawPixmap(target,pixmap,source)
```

This leaves me very puzzled and very very confused.
Which of these ways should I use to get the highest quality of Images and geometric figures both on video and in print?

Comment: The second and fourth ways are identical

Comment: ... opps, sorry.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738285/qpainter-or-qlabel-is-less-costly-to-draw-qpixmap/28738463#28738463